# Integrating multivatiate gaussian for likelihood

Tags: integration, statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian, maximum-likelihood

[image]

I want to calulate the likelihood by evaluating the second integral , I am supposed to get the third step but I don't seem to get it , how do I evaluate the integra l

Answer (score 0):

The related conclusion and derivation can be found in [PRML](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2006/01/Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006.pdf) Chapter 2.3.3.

The derivation there avoids the integral. We can first obtain the joint distribution of $(Z, Y)$ through the covariance matrix in Eqn. (2.105) and the expectation in Eqn. (2.108), and then simply pick the expectation and variance of $Z$, which induces the density in your third step.